# Join on partial column to compare ERP CRM codes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We're integrating our erp and crm. We want to compare lookup codes. The erp has codes in the code table, code_value column. The crm has a lookup table with a delimiter of // in the column. For example, the crm has state with the state abbreviation and // then the state long name. VA// VIRGINIA. It has the country code split with the first 15 characters and a //. I need to do left and right joins on the code_value column and the crm entry column on the characters before the // to find codes that don't match so we can update those to match. How do I join on the characters before the // delimiter? The position will change. There are many other codes to compare but the pattern is the same. The charters before the // delimiter in the crm match the erp. I need something like join on the length of the column before the // characters.

version sql server 2008r

```
erp
code table
code_value column
united states of america
Equatorial Guinea
VA
VI

crm 
lookup table
entry
united states o//f america
Equatorial Guin//ea
VA// VIRGINIA
VI// VIRGIN ISLANDS

SELECT LOOKUP_CODE, CODE_VALUE_KEY, CODE_VALUE, SHORT_DESC, MEDIUM_DESC, LONG_DESC, 
FIELDNAME, LOOKUPSUPP, ENTRY, MASTERVALUE, U_ENTRY, recid
FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW LEFT JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM ON PW.MEDIUM_DESC = GM.ENTRY --need to join on first 15 characters
```

Comment: It may be worthwhile to add a _persisted computed column_ for the split value. The result can be indexed. That ought to improve the performance of joins considerably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add LEFT() function to the on join part
it will look like this **LEFT(GM.ENTRY, 15)**

```
    SELECT LOOKUP_CODE, CODE_VALUE_KEY, CODE_VALUE, SHORT_DESC, MEDIUM_DESC, LONG_DESC, FIELDNAME, LOOKUPSUPP, ENTRY, MASTERVALUE, U_ENTRY, recid

    FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW 
    LEFT JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM 
    ON LEFT(PW.MEDIUM_DESC, CharIndex('//', GM.ENTRY) -1) = LEFT(GM.ENTRY, CharIndex('//', GM.ENTRY ) -1)
```

Comment: then it has state like erp
code table
code_value column
united states of america
Equatorial Guinea
VA
VI

crm 
lookup table
entry
united states o//f america
Equatorial Guin//ea
VA// VIRGINIA
VI// VIRGIN ISLANDS

Comment: The // is only in the gm.entry column. Do I only need that charindex function on the gm.entry? It looks like the charindex will be 16th for country and 3 for state. Do i need to do -1?

Comment: I get an error Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.
SELECT     LOOKUP_CODE, CODE_VALUE_KEY, CODE_VALUE, SHORT_DESC, MEDIUM_DESC, LONG_DESC, 
FIELDNAME, LOOKUPSUPP, ENTRY, MASTERVALUE, U_ENTRY, recid
  --FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM ON PW.MEDIUM_DESC = GM.ENTRY 
  FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM ON PW.MEDIUM_DESC = LEFT(GM.ENTRY, (CharIndex(GM.ENTRY, '//')-1))

Comment: it runs for minutes and doesn't finish

Comment: --SELECT CHARINDEX('//','VI// VIRGIN ISLANDS'); --result 3
  --SELECT (CHARINDEX('//','VI// VIRGIN ISLANDS')-1); --result 2

Comment: maybe if i have -1 on some rows it's returning a length less than 1

Comment: Oh the left pw.medium_desc, won't have a delimiter. Do I have to do trim to the length of pw.medium_desc, and upper to match case? And find the position of // -1 in GM.ENTRY

Comment: Also the CharIndex has been modified, I tested it myself and it is working fine now

Comment: SELECT     LOOKUP_CODE, CODE_VALUE_KEY, CODE_VALUE, SHORT_DESC, MEDIUM_DESC, LONG_DESC, 
FIELDNAME, LOOKUPSUPP, ENTRY, MASTERVALUE, U_ENTRY, recid
  --FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM ON PW.MEDIUM_DESC = GM.ENTRY 
  FROM Bridge_Test.DBO.CODE_TABLE PW JOIN GoldMine_test.dbo.LOOKUP GM 
  ON PW.MEDIUM_DESC = LEFT(GM.ENTRY, (CharIndex(GM.ENTRY, '//')-1))  --Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function
I think I have to check first that the string is 1 or greater

Comment: Change the CharIndex as in the query in the answer , you are using CharIndex(GM.ENTRY, '//') it should be CharIndex('//', GM.ENTRY)

Comment: I read this on another post. If there is no @ symbol in the data, charindex returns 0. You subtract one from that to get -1, which is invalid in the substring function. This forces there to be a match. If I use that with // then it doesn't get the error Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function .

Try this instead.

CHARINDEX('@',[email] + '@')-1